# How to create @Index on @ManyToOne fields?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to create an `@Index` using hibernate. The index should consist of 3 fields, where some of them are nested within other entities. How can I achieve this?

```
@Table(name = "my_entity", indexes = {
@Index(name = "my_index", columnList = "id, person.firstname, person.lastname")
})
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
   private Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   private Person person;
}

@Entity
public class Person { 
   @Id private Long id;
   private String firstname;
   private String lastname;
}
```

Result:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (id, person.firstname, person.lastname) on table my_entity: database column 'person.firstname', 'person.lastname' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames(Configuration.java:1684)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1459)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857)
    ... 46 more
```

Comment: Looks like you havent mapped Person to a table?  Also, I think it should be Person.firstname and Person.lastname (capital P).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`columnList` takes an array of **column** names. Not an array of entity properties.

So you just need to provide the names of the columns in the test table, as you would do if you defined the index using SQL.

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Index.html)

Comment: So would I have to index `columnList = "id, fk_person_id"`? And if, how would I write my native query if I want to search for these 3 fields? `select * from my_entity where id = :id and <person.firstname> = :firstname and <person.lastname> = :lastname`?

Comment: If the column of the test table is named "fk_person_id", yes. The way you write a native query doesn't have anything to do with the index defined on a table. The index is only used by the database to make queries faster, when possible, by using the index instead of scanning the table. You need to learn basic joins in SQL: select * from test t inner join person p on t.fk_person_id  =  p.id where t.id = :id and p.firstname = :firstName and p.lastName = :lastName.

Comment: @membersound How did you solve it in your example `@Index(name = "my_index", columnList = "id, person.firstname, person.lastname")`. The answer is at least to me not very clear.

Comment: @momo `columnList = id, firstname, lastname`, exactly written like your sql fields, not your java entity fields.

Comment: @membersound yes, that's what I tried and it didn't work for me. I uploaded your example here: https://github.com/marodev/springJpaRelationIndex.git

Comment: Sorry, my issue is way too old to remember. Afaik you cannot create an index on a `@ManyToOne` subfield. Because in `sql` they would result in an additional table. And you cannot create sql indexes over multiple tables. Thus, you only chance would be to include the foreign key id in the index (eg `fk_person_id` in my example).

Answer (score -2):

What you try to do here is to create an index over 2 different tables (MyEntity and Person), thus it's impossible.
If you want to do that you have to embed the Person class like this :

```
@Table(name = "test", indexes = {
@Index(name = "my_index", columnList = "id, person.firstname, person.lastname")
})
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
   private Long id;
   private Person person;
}

@Embeddable
public class Person {
   private String firstname;
   private String lastname;
}
```

Note that I've remplaced @Entity by @Embeddable on the Person class, this way in the database you'll have one table named Test with the columns id, firstname and lastname

Comment: I cannot embed the `Person` class. Is there any other way achieving this?

Comment: My bad I didn't saw the manyToOne annotation. But why does your Person entity (and maybe Table) doesn't have an id ?